# Kotlinic way to enforce methods return a specific type

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am relatively new to kotlin so my apologies if this is not possible.

I have a data class ApiResponse that I want to be returned by all API routes.

So I'm curious if there is something like

```
class ExampleApiController implements ApiController {
  fun foo(): ApiResponse
  fun bar(): ApiResponse
}
```

where something possible such that the ApiController interface requires at compile time that all public methods of the class have to return the type  ApiResponse.

Please ignore the correctness of this approach. It will only be temporary and will be replaced by a response/exception mapper; I am just curious if this is possible at all.

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do this, but without more details it's not possible to know if any of them will work for you. Smells a lot like an XY problem anyway.

Comment: What details would you need? The ask more succinctly is, how would one require that any method of classes implementing a particular interface return the same type?

Comment: This would be logically impossible. Classes already have `toString()` and `hashcode()` that must return String and Int as a requirement. There’s no logical reason to prevent extra functions with other types, anyway. If you don’t want to use them, just don’t use them. Forbidding them would also go against the spirit of the Liskov substitution principle. If you upcast your data class to the interface type, that erases the visibility of its other functions anyway.

Comment: *All* public methods have to return `ApiResponse`?  I think you might be able do this by implementing an Annotation which you add to each Controller and then an Annotation Processor.  Here's an article on writing your own Annotation Processor: https://www.willowtreeapps.com/craft/generating-code-via-annotations-in-kotlin But as Tenfour04 says, you are going to have to make exceptions for methods like `toString()`

Comment: I think a compile time check would be more trouble than it would be worth. If using Kotlin/JVM it might be possible to write a [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/) test.